# Best web resources for java developer

Tags: java

Each Java developer has his each day sites, I want to ask more experienced Java developers about list of web resources that they will recommend to less experienced Java developers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com)
- [http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) for javadoc :)
- any official document for respective framework (for example:[springsource.org](http://springsource.org) for spring )

Comment: It's a recursive answer, I like it...

Comment: I also like this answer, but docs doesn't always help to program effective , for example I never used enum for game status before read it from some blog.

Comment: docs will certainly help you in many cases .and agree with your example

Answer (score 2):

I like to add official Oracle(Sun) Java tutorial, which I feel must for a beginner in Java

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

You might be look at Joshua Bloch's book "Effective Java": [http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-2nd-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)

This is great book about Java program design.

Answer (score 1):

- Read the Javadocs.  Become familiar with the structure as all Javadoc API specs will follow this pattern.
- I use Google in general to find solutions to problems.  I don't rely on any one given site.  Generally, a Google search with the right keywords will yield the best results when searching for the solution to a problem.
- It also depends on the context of what you're searching for.  If you have a Spring problem, go to http://forum.springsource.org/.  If you have a Google App Engine problem, search Google Groups.  This rule isn't always true for every tool in your toolbox because sometimes the information is just plain better and more organized in other sources.
- Some problems are also very specific and may not be covered specifically in the documentation.  It really just depends on the problem.

But in summary, I suggest getting really good at learning to use Google to find information quickly while also weeding out anything that's not relevant to you.

Answer (score 1):

These are my favorite sites (rss enabled):

[http://www.javaspecialists.co.za](http://www.javaspecialists.co.za/) - Problems in Java

http://javaposse.com - New frameworks, random links to java news.

Answer (score 1):

@Bojan Milenkoski is right. 
You cant find solution to all problems in single place. One site may be good in Collections but poor in  Objects  and  Data types .
It also depends on how depth you need your answer