# Java libraries and frameworks overviews

Tags: java

Which web sites could you recommend, where I shall find overviews of different java libraries and frameworks that are currently preferable to use in development of applications?

*update:* To be more precise, I've liked to find a site that will be like a magazine about java, where will be the overviews, comparisons, best practices, examples and other useful information about java (technics, libraries, frameworks and so on) for different purposes. The aim of magazines is not to cover all the things of their subject area, but to present more actual, interesting and useful things only.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623905/best-web-resources-for-java-developer#4623932

Comment: I don't see nothing wrong with the question. Upvoted to cancel the downvote :)

Comment: @Bogdan he won't get notified this way :)

Comment: http://java-source.net/open-source/web-frameworks

Comment: I agree it is a legitimate question, but isn't it tremendously broad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I really like the design on [Open Source Software in Java](http://java-source.net/). They've got it laid out by type to start with, plus when you dig down you can find several competing projects for each category.

For example clicking on 'HTML Parsers' gives this (and more - this is just a partial clip):
[image: java-source.net example]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Didn't know about this. Looks pretty interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The world of java has so many libraries that it would be practically impossible to recommend anything without some kind of understanding about what kind of application you are actually writing. Are you writing a blu-ray disc, a game for a java phone, an android app, a desktop application, a server side computation process, a web service, a web site.... the list of things that java can and does do is huge.

The same thing goes for frameworks too. I would always say (although many people on this site disagree) that you should  only look for a framework when you are finding something difficult, and the framework makes that thing easier, without making other stuff harder. Some people say you pick your framework first.....

Perhaps if you gave more details on what kind of thing you were trying to attempt, the community might be able to point you towards some useful stuff.

As a side note, remember that the internet is full of people with opinions - just because they are loud, it doesn't make them right - after all http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you%27re_a_dog